# What is this cable hanging down and should it be connected to anything?

Tags: motorcycle, part-identification, yamaha

I have a Yamaha XJ6N, when I was washing it today I noticed a cable poking out that I've never noticed before. Wondering what it is/if it should be connected to anything:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know where it goes, but it looks like some kind of vacuum line. If the other end is coming from the carb or intake area, it should be plugged into something. If you cannot figure it out right away, you'll want to plug it off until you can get it to someone who can place it for you.

Comment: As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, is it part of the crankcase ventilation? is there a hole close by?

Comment: It's a vent line. I've got two of them on my bike. It's odd that there is a nipple plugged into it. Perhaps they use that line in the manufacturing process?  I'd guess to suck a vacuum for quick oil fill?

Comment: @zipzit I don't think it is a vent line. I've also got two on my bike too and they end just above the belly pan. I'm sorry for the lack of detail on the nipple: I went back to look at it and it doesn't have any kind of hole in it - so no air can escape/enter. This makes me think that it's some kind of sensor...

Comment: On further searching I found this site: http://www.600cc.org/forum/f91/how-sync-throttle-bodies-fz6r-15991/

It says that these are vacuum lines (nice, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 !) that were fitted to attach a sync gauge to, if you need to. Apparently the pink band indicates it's attached to the no.1 cylinder. I'm not completely fluent in the language used and don't understand all of it but it leads me to believe that this isn't attached to anything/hasn't become unattached: it is only a tool to make "debugging" the engine easier. If this is also called a vent line... sorry for saying it's not, zipzit!

Comment: *no.1 throttle body, not no.1 cylinder (as written ^). & **"debugging" the throttle body, not the engine (as written^). I think I understand it all a bit more, now...!